# mod rewrite for two separate folders

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a script that creates a pretty directory listing of a folder.  I called it an mydrive.  I have two foders, public and private, and I'm having issues rerouting people with pretty urls.

Files placed in: /mydrive/public/folder1
get called with: /mydrive/files/mydrive.cgi?path=public/folder1

Files placed in: /mydrive/private/folder1
get called with: /mydrive/files/mydrive.cgi?path=private/folder1

I'd like it to work like this:

URL: www.domain.com/mydrive/folder1 
Calls: /mydrive/files/mydrive.cgi?path=public/folder1

URL: www.domain.com/mydrive/private/folder1 
Calls: /mydrive/files/mydrive.cgi?path=private/folder1

I've tried several recipes but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/mydrive/(private/.*)$ /mydrive/files/mydrive.cgi?path=$1 [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/mydrive/(.*)$ /mydrive/files/mydrive.cgi?path=public/$1 [PT,L]
```

should do the trick, if you place it in your virtualserver configuration.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work.  I'm getting a not found error with the pretty URL.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your question exactly enough. Try the updated rules, please.